# Clearing cache manifest via CLI

Tags: php, caching, silverstripe

I've automated the deploying of my site and I have a script that runs `framework/sake /dev/build "flush=1"` This works however it clears the cache directory of the user who runs it, which is different from the apache user (which I can't run it from).

I've read a few bug reports and people talking about it on the SS forum however either there is no answer or it doesn't work for example

```
define('MANIFEST_FILE', TEMP_FOLDER . "/manifest-main");
```

I thought about just deleting the cache directory however it's a randomised string so not easy to script.

Whats the best way to clear the cache via command line?

Comment: Can you run sake as apache? `sudo -u apache php framework/cli-script.php dev/build flush=1`

Comment: @RobbieAverill Am surprised I can because apache isn't a real user under CentOS however it doesn't clear the correct cache. Normal cache sits under `/tmp/systemd-private-***httpd/tmp/ss-website/apache` but running the above command from the command line clears `/tmp/ss-website/apache`

Comment: Perhaps if I create the `silverstripe-cache` directory that could make it work?

Comment: yeah that works. so combination of creating a cache directory in the web path and running the sake command from the apache user. (I'm running `/framework/sake dev/build "flush=1"`)

Comment: I'm no Linux guru but I think the user can be mimicked but not interactively

Comment: Yeah, neither am I. Just knew it wasn't a real user so wasn't sure the limitation. If you wanted to make this an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: It was mostly you that figured it out! You should answer t yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work you need to first move the cache from the default directory to within the web directory by creating a folder `silverstripe-cache` at the web root. Also make sure the path is read/write (SS default config blocks this being readable by the public)

Then you can script:

```
sudo -u apache /path/to/web/root/framework/sake dev/build "flush=1"
```